# Spring Integration for Apache Kafka, how to pass on environment(dev/stage/prod) specific properties to the xml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am very new to spring-integration,
we are using xml file to implement apache kafka using spring-integration, there are some properties like topic name, broker list that are getting read from application.properties as of now using ${topic.name} etc. read inside

```
<bean>
<constructor-arg>
<map></map>
</constructor-arg>
</bean> 
<int:chain>
</int:chain>
```

Now to expand it as per different environments, I can't just read it from application.properties file, need to read it from env specific properties config files.

How can I pass those properties to xml? Do I have to use any Java config class in between though service-activator or transformer?

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The `dev/stage/prod` sounds like a `profile`. See if you can can profile-specific bean definitions or properties placeholder configurations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-environment